# WMI on guest Windows account

Tags: windows, wmi

I develop program on Delphi XE3. Program should read hardware information by WMI. My code:

```
var
  SWbemLocator1: ISWbemLocator;
  Service:  ISWbemServices;
  ...
begin
  CoInitialize(nil);  

  SWbemLocator1 := CoSWbemLocator.Create();  
  Service:= SWbemLocator1.ConnectServer('.', 'root\CIMV2', '', '', '', '', 0, nil);
  ...
```

It works perfect, but in guest Windows account ConnectServer call an exception "Access denied" and it doesn't work. Administrator and user account works well. Testing on Windows Vista/7.

How can I fix it?

Comment: Related: [WMI Access Denied on XP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2061394/wmi-access-denied-on-xp)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I fix it?

This question pre-supposes that something is broken. That is not so and this behaviour is by design. The guest account is highly limited in what it is allowed to do.

If you wish to allow guest user access to WMI then you will need to modify the guest user's rights to grant it more power. You should think twice about doing so. This article discusses required WMI user rights in some detail: http://community.zenoss.org/thread/12048